Typescript SWAP ETH -> USDC failing
I wrote a code in typescript to realize a ETH -> USDC swap, but i am having some problems when realizing. The code runs smooth, but when i check in etherscan, i see a failure in Uniswap V3 Router. Does somebody know what can be these errors?
Here is my repo: https://github.com/rafaelpolonio92/uniswap-trade-base-chain



Obviously there isn't information here to give you an answer as the error message is too generic

@Torof how can i debug this application? I mean, when i run the script, nothing fails, but i see these errors and i dont have idea what to do. Just see an error during contract execution
